# How to access my Home Server from subdomain.mydomain.com

Tags: dns, debian, nameserver

I've just set up my home server, located at home ;)

Now I want to access it (e.g. via SSH) from work.

What I do have:

- vServer (root login)
- vServer has a Static IP
- vServer runs Debian 6.0.9 with Plesk 11.5
- I own several domains (let's call one mydomain.com)
- Unfortunately a dynamic home IP address

What I want:
- Access my home server from home.mydomain.com

I **can** login to my home server by using the home IP address

The problem:
- Home IP address changes every 24 hours

What I could do:
- Register at DynDNS services like noip.com, then tell my domain provider the noip.com domain so he can enter it as a CNAME for home.mydomain.com

**But I don't want to use 3rd party services like noip.com.**

What could I do to get everything working as expected?

Comment: If you don't want to use a DDNS service, you'll have to run your own DNS server. This server will, of course, require a static IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dynamic DNS service. Like No-Ip or DynDns. Configure the DUC client with your user at the dynamic DNS service of your choice. Then, at your router you have to redirect all the connections using the SSH port to your IP server.